# ion-refresher in col for tablet

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, pull-to-refresh

I have a problem with the ion-refresher

This is my content

```html
<ion-content #scrollContent [scrollEvents]="true" class="line-top-hide">
  <ion-grid class="ion-no-padding split-layout-wrapper">
    <ion-row class="split-layout">
      <ion-col class="ion-no-padding split-layout__left" size="12" size-md="7" size-lg="8">
        <!-- some content with scroll stuff -->
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col class="ion-no-padding split-layout__right" size="12" size-md="5" size-lg="4">
        <!-- some other content no scroll stuff -->
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="pullToRefresh($event)">
       <ion-refresher-content
        [refreshingSpinner]="'lines-small'"
        [pullingIcon]="'/assets/icons/icon_arrow_bottom_grey.svg'"
       ></ion-refresher-content>
     </ion-refresher>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

When i open the app now on a tablet, i have content on the left and right side.
Now when i can scroll down the left content and i want to scroll back on top, the refresher will be triggered. How can i prevent this?
I just want to trigger ion-refresher, when i have all scrolled to top.

Comment: where's the ion-grid tag? you need to place this code inside of a ion-grid. Also to answer your question, no you can prevent it. the ion-refresher is working as intended.

Comment: sorry i forgot to put it in here. There is a ion-grif.
So you say, it's not possible?

Comment: I just realised, that ion-refresher only triggers, if in shadowdom of ion-content, the scroll-content::after element is scrolled all to top. But i can't manipulate with js.